Cryptography on other SE sites, notably Theoretical Computer Science and Security
There are still a sizable amount of questions about Cryptography asked at Security.SE and Theoretical Computer Science. That there are questions about cryptography (/encryption) at Security.SE is not much of a surprise; I didn't expect that there are still questions accepted at CS though.
We are getting more and more cryptography related questions from Security.SE, although unfortunately this doesn't always include the user asking the questions.
However, when looking at the tag cr.crypto-security the tag info reads:

Before posting a theoretical question about cryptography, you may want to search Cryptography Stack Exchange first.

Should we (i.e. the mods) further discuss the topic with the site mods from Security and TCS. Or are we OK with the fact that there are still questions asked on those sites that are directly targeting cryptography?

Looking at their questions, I'm fine with keeping those over there.

Don't forget about Math.SE. They get a fair number of crypto questions. I often just leave a comment on the good ones pointing the asker to our site.

To keep it short, I'll echo @CodesInChaos' comment.

So in conclusion: you're all already on the case and we should only do something in addition to what is done now if the situation changes. Is that a good answer?

I guess the mods want to leave it this way for the time being (and I'm actually fine with that).
